# How can I get the gridview header's text that is clicked by the user 

Tags: asp.net, gridview, headertext

I had a grid view populated from dataset and I have to redirect another page when user clicks on gridview header.
How can I get the gridview header's text that is clicked by the user .
I tried some code here...

```
protected void gv2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {            
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='/SampleProgram/AnotherPage.aspx?empid=" + e.Row .Cells[0].Text+ "'");//this will give me first column header's text.

        }
    }
```

Thx a lot for your help and interest...

Comment: and what exactly is not working? when the HTML is rendered, does the header have an `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to another page when a user clicks on the GridView header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer..

```
 foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                    {
                        cell.Attributes.Add("id", _i.ToString());
                        cell.Attributes.Add("onClick", "location='/SampleProgram/AnotherPage.aspx?empid="+e.Row.Cells[_i].Text+"'");  
                        _i++;
                    }
```

使ってみてください。 :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution from the jQuery:

```
$("table").delegate("th", "click", function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    alert("th:" + $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(i).text());
});
```

The above code will get you the Table header in the Gridview.
You can try the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/niteshkatare/3B4z3/
Using the jQuery value you can redirect the user to the different page.